# How I can separate the array elements by a comma and a single space?

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic3

Look at the below given code:-

```
<td class="w3-theme-d4">{{profile.webSite}}</td>
```

Now here the expression contains the array of all the website's entered by the user. When I display it in front end like this, it separates them with a comma but I want it to be separated using a comma and a single space.

Comment: can you add  {{profile.webSite}} output value ??

Comment: i didn't get you!

Comment: now what you get this expression {{profile.webSite}}  what is your excepted output,

Comment: I want it as "abc.com, def.com, efg.com", while now it is coming as "abc.com,def.com,efg.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass through what you want to join

```
<td class="w3-theme-d4">{{profile.webSite.join(', ')}}</td>
```

Comment: I tried this... but still it gives me the same output

Comment: Try this edited code, If this doesn't work - are you sure `profile.webSite` is an array?

Comment: Thanks for the solution! the previous one only worked. I made a minor typing mistake... Thanks

Comment: You mean `profile.webSite.join(', ')` worked? I'm editing the answer to previous solution then - so that others can get help in future

Comment: @SunnyParekh if this answered your question, could you please mark it as accepted so we can close the issue? Thanks.